# java all values int[] 0

Tags: java, arrays, int

For a minigame written in java, I have a main level and a background level. The player is only able to walk in the mail level, and the background level is solely for decoration. Ive written a method which checks for all the visible background tiles, and puts the coordinates of these tiles in a int[][][]. The array is threedimensional, because the background is also threedimensional. Because the background is not always visible, I thought I could save quite some processing time by first checking whether even a single background tile was visible. In other words, checking whether the array containing all the visible background tiles, has any value written in any slot. When a tile is visible, that coordinate in the array becomes 1, and otherwise, it remains at its default value (0 I thought). Do you guys know a good way to effectively check whether the array contains a value, so the program doesn't have to browse through every single slot, 60 times a second?

Comment: Code is worth 1,024 words...

Comment: I would do this using the graphics processor rather than trying to do this in Java.  Draw multiple images with transparent portions.  This can be 100x faster than trying to do it in Java.

Comment: Why not count the number of tiles visible during insertion and _append_ this _information_ in the array? So you would've to check only one single _space_ rather than every single slot..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go through the whole array every time, then you could keep a flag or similar that tells you whether there are any visible.

Even though you should have plenty of computing power to go through the array 60 times per second :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's a built in mechanism for checking if an array is completely empty in Java. However, unless your array is truly massive, you shouldn't underestimate your computer; it shouldn't really take much processing power to check the array 60 times a second.

Alternatively, you could maintain a `count` property or something like that; increment it whenever you change an array element to 1, and decrement it whenever you set an element back to `null`. Whenever the `count` is 0, you can assume that the array is empty.

Also, it's important to note that, in Java, array slots are initialized to `null`, not 0.

Comment: It's an `int[]`, so the slots are indeed initialized to 0.

Comment: But `int[][][]` is an array of references to `int[][]` arrays of references to `int[]` arrays of `int`s.